# QThread not emiting my own signal

Tags: python, qt, signals, pyside

I need to emit my own signal using QThreads but it is still not working. This is my Thread class:

```
class Thread(QThread):

    startDestroy = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Thread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.startDestroy.emit()
```

signal startDestroy needs to be emitted:

My main class:

```
class MainForm(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self):
       super(MainForm, self).__init__()
       .
       .
       .
       self.thread = Thread()

    def setupSignals(self):
       .
       .
       .
       self.thread.startDestroy.connect(self.strDestroy)
```

And I only get this error, I dont know why:

> self.thread.startDestroy.connect(self.strDestroy)
>      AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'startDestroy'

Comment: apparently `startDestroy` does not exist...

Comment: why not? You can "see" it from class MainForm

Comment: This class name `Thread` may be problematic are you sure that you are using class implemented by you or maybe something else from other none qt module.

Comment: I changed the name to "Vlakno". Now I´m getting this error:

Comment: 'MainForm' object has no attribute 'vlakno'

Comment: I was writing about CLASS name not FIELD name! + Case sensitivity!

Comment: I renamed class name to MyOwnThread. Constructor is now self.vlakno = MyOwnThread()

Comment: self.vlakno.startDestroy.connect(self.strDestroy)
AttributeError: 'MainForm' object has no attribute 'vlakno'

Comment: where are your calling `setupSignals` from? if you call it from within `__init__`, then it must be after setting the `thread` (or `vlakno`) property!

Comment: thank you, now I can execute it. But my GUI is still freezing